# Google play services crashing on android mobile yu yureka with cynogen mod12

Tags: android, mobile, crash, google-play-services, crash-reports

Google play services is crashing on android mobile `yu` `yureka` with `cyanogenmod 12`.
The problem mainly happens when I connect my phone to wifi. 
Its happening very frequently. Can someone help?

The error message stack trace is here

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wake lock not active: android.os.BinderProxy@122b90e3 from uid 10013
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1544)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
at android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.updateWakeLockWorkSource(IPowerManager.java:500)
at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.setWorkSource(PowerManager.java:1191)
at com.google.android.gms.stats.c.a(SourceFile:393)
at com.google.android.location.reporting.service.f.a(SourceFile:754)
at com.google.android.location.reporting.service.d.handleMessage(SourceFile:463)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this [page](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/google-play-services-errors.311899/), They solved the same error/crashes by following this answers:

- try to uninstall the google play service then install it again.
- uninstalling the updates on Google Play Service and update it again in the the pay store.
- clearing the data from Google Play Service, by following this steps.
  `Settings > apps > google play services > manage space > clear all data`. Usually it resolve most of the crashes.

> Also the IllegalArgumentException indicates that the argument supplied
>   to a method or function are not valid for their intended purpose, or a
>   different to the format expected by the method.